# UITableView and Scroll issue with UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, ios8, autolayout

I have UITextView inside TableView and I am using UITableViewAutomaticDimension to calculate 
Cell Height.

but the problem is once i start typing in UITextView the TableView Start Shaking Up & Down !

below my code in textViewDidChange event:

```
ImageDescriptionTableViewCell *cell = (ImageDescriptionTableViewCell *)textView.superview.superview ;
NSInteger index = [self.TableViewController indexPathForCell:cell].row;
[self.cellTextArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:textView.text];

[self.TableViewController beginUpdates];
[self.TableViewController endUpdates];
```

constraints in Table View Cell :

```
[self.ImageDetails addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[flebImageDetails(300@999)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"ImageDetails":self.ImageDetails}]];

[self.ImageDetails addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[ImageDetails(>=30)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"ImageDetails":self.ImageDetails}]];

[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[ImageDetails]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"ImageDetails":self.ImageDetails}]];

[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[ImageDetails]-5-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"ImageDetails":self.ImageDetails}]];
```

Please help i am with issue from 1 weak ago .

Answer (score -1):

I dont believe you need the beginUpdates and endUpdates in the text change event. These are only required if you are modifying (ie adding, deleting etc) multiple rows and want them animated as a single unit. Updating a text field does not require them.